# VS Code + Pymakr : the strip is not displayed

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-code, esp32

I installed node.js, restart computer and installed Pymakr (direct from marketplace in VS Code). But the strip at the window bottom with for example "All commands" is not displayed.

What could be the error ? I installed the last version for everything (Pymakr v2.22.5).

Thanks !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When you install the extension Pymakr in VScode, it should appera at the bottom of the windows (of VScode) a purple bar with some options. By me, this bar is not appearing.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same error

Comment: Unfortunately no